# Вывод записей в single.php за исключением самой записи

Tags: php, wordpress

вывожу через single.php записи по категориям

```
    <div class="services-card-single-row">
            <?php
            $query = new WP_Query( array(
                'category_name' => 'heading_our_services',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'ASC',
            )  );
            if( $query->have_posts() ){
                while( $query->have_posts() ){
                    $query->the_post();

                    ?>
                        <a class="services-card-single" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">  <?php the_title();  ;?> </a>
                    <?php
                }
                wp_reset_postdata(); // сбрасываем переменную $post
            }
            else
                echo 'Записей нет.';
            ?>
        </div>
```

И потом в сам шаблон вывожу ссылку на все остальные записи рубрики.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Как исключить из списка ту рубрику на которой ты находишься?

Comment: Вообще известно как получить текущую рубрику?

Comment: get_the_category()

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_category

Comment: В цикле делаете проверку, и в случае совпадения просто пропускаете текущую итерацию, не пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо ! В цикле пробовал но выводило 4 записи из 6 а должно 5 из 6 за исключением текущей.  Решение нашел  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) Есть уже готовое оказывается =)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="services-card-single-row">
            <?php
            $query = new WP_Query( array(
                'category_name' => 'heading_our_services',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post_parent' => 0,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)

            )  );
            if( $query->have_posts() ){
                while( $query->have_posts() ){
                    $query->the_post();

                    ?>

                        <div class="services-card-single">
                            <div class="services-card-single__title">
                                <?php the_title();  ;?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="services-card-single__description">
                                <?php echo CFS()->get( 'services-card-single__description' ); ?>
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="services-card-single_button">ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>

                        </div>
                    <?php
                }
                wp_reset_postdata(); // сбрасываем переменную $post
            }
            else
                echo 'Записей нет.';
            ?>
        </div>
```

Пришлось добавить только одну строчку    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) в массив.